# Python find text with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
< br/>

My name is Jonas< br/>

< br/>
```

How to extract: `My name is Jonas`

Using regex :

```
regex = re.findall(r"< br/>\ n.*< br/>\ n< br/>")
```

Added additional spaces cause otherwise stack would not able to read correctly.
But overall code doesn`t do what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you have more than one break line `\n` so instead you can use `\n*` which mean zero or more break line.
Beside you have to use `\n` and not `\ n`

try to use this regex `< br/>\n*(.*)< br/>\n*< br/>`

#### regex demo

and try this :

```
import re

line = "< br/>"\
""\
"My name is Jonas< br/>"\
""\
"< br/>";
print(re.findall('< br/>\n*(.*)< br/>\n*< br/>', line));
=> ['My name is Jonas']
```

#### Live demo

Comment: FYI: Constructing a character class for a newline character alone, isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of the regex groups in python:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

`regex = re.findall(r"< br/>\n(.+?)< br/>\ n< br/>")`